# PyTorch different between ones_tensor = torch.ones((2, 3,)) and ones_tensor = torch.ones(2, 3)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

In PyTorch, what is different between

```py
ones_tensor = torch.ones((2, 3,))
```

and

```py
ones_tensor = torch.ones(2, 3)
```

?

Comment: The documentation allows both possibilities: "a sequence of integers defining the shape of the output tensor. Can be a variable number of arguments or a collection like a list or tuple."  This doesn't cause any ambiguity because all the other parameters of the function are keyword-only.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between the two. As stated in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.ones.html#torch-ones),

> size (int...) – a sequence of integers defining the shape of the output tensor. Can be a variable number of arguments or a collection like a list or tuple.

If you test it, they both produce the same tensor with the same shape.

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1.]])

torch.Size([2, 3])
```